# What happens when partition Kafka is full?

Tags: apache-kafka

Does it put data to another partition that was configured before launching Kafka?

What is benefit and major reason to have more partition as usual 3?

How it affects on the reading, writing performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having a bit of trouble understanding your question but I think you may be misinterpreting what a partition actually is. A partition only has a limit if you specify it in the config, otherwise you can simply think of a partition as a separate stream of data that contains an offset. In actuality the limit on the size of a partition (or topic for that matter) is simply what the disk capacity will allow. Often the data will stay there and get deleted once a specified retention period or max size/data limit has been reached.

The list of configurations is pretty extensive but you can view it here:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration

As for you other question about the reasoning for having more partitions well it simply comes down to scaling. If you only have s small amount of data then a small number of partitions will be enough. With kafka there is no benefit to having multiple consumers per partitions. I.e. if you have three partitions then three consumers is the most optimal number of consumers you can have as each consumer will be assigned to a single partition. If you have more consumers, some will sit idle.

So what if we have more data and need to read it faster to avoid lag? Well we can add more partitions and by doing so we can also scale up the number of consumers.

Side note. You can have a single consumer that reads from multiple partitions but this will become an issue because reassigning partitions takes time and if you have too few consumers compared to the number of partitions they simply won't be able to deal with high loads due to the time of reassignment where no processing is happening.